# Dmidecode maximum supported memory?

Tags: lenovo, ram, dmidecode, memory-card

I tried
`$ sudo dmidecode -t memory` command and  [this picture is result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V4jmZ.png)

So under `Physical Memory Array`  it says `Maximum Capacity: 32 GB`.
So can i use 2 `32GB Ram` or Just 2 `16GB Ram`?
I mean 32GB is maximum of each Memory slot or both memory slot?
Is `dmidecode` trustable? can i trust this information ? Because i want to buy memory so i should know maximum supported memory of my `Motherboard` . my `Motherboard` model is `LNVNB161216`
Thank you guys

Comment: It is better to look into the MB manual. Also not all modules may be supported.

Comment: Please never post screenshots of text.

Comment: how can i find supported modules? @Pilot6

Comment: Download a manual from a vendor site and read it.

Comment: Yep, you can't always trust dmidecode.  My motherboard says a maximum of 16GB but I know for certain that it will do at least 32GB.  Best to consult the motherboard manufacturer for the best info for RAM upgrades like Pilot6 has suggested here.

Comment: 32 GB is the maximum for the two memory banks combined.